# Docker-compose: node_modules mouting as volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have an app with the following services:

- `cockpit/` - use as a headless CMS service.
- `frontend/` - bootstrapped by Create React App.

I have a question about `frontend`

#### `frontend/Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:12.16.3-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json yarn.lock /app/

RUN yarn install --pure-lockfile
COPY . /app

CMD ["yarn", "run", "start"]
```

#### `docker-compose.yml`

```
    frontend:
        ...
        volumes:
            - ./frontend:/app
            - /app/node_modules
```

The question is `/app/node_modules` is same meaning with `./frontend/node_modules:/app/node_modules` ?

If not, what is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/app/node_modules` creates a directory inside the container and the Docker Engine automatically creates an anonymous volume for this (i.e. it should will probably be empty). This is from [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes) about the compose file spec in the "Short Syntax" section.

`./frontend/node_modules:/app/node_modules` creates a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/). The `./frontend/node_modules` directory from your host machine will be shared with the container.

In response to followups regarding why using `/app/node_modules` works but the other syntax does not:

Your `yarn install` command creates a `node_modules` folder inside the Docker image. This created folder conflicts with the existing `frontend/node_modules` folder you have locally when trying to run with `./frontend/node_modules:/app/node_modules`. When you specify `/app/node_modules`, the container uses the directory created during the build step.

Comment: `/app/node_modules` works properly, but `./frontend/node_modules:/app/node_modules` doesn't work. what is the problem?

Comment: Sorry @WilliamWang I did not understand from your question that one worked and the other did not. Can you elaborate on what exactly doesn't work? Does the docker-compose service fail to start up and if so, what errors are there?

Comment: 1. i'm doing `docker-compose up` in my local, and when I delete on my local frontend/node_modules, `/app/node_modules` works, but `./frontend/node_modules:/app/node_module` doesn't work.

Comment: 2. i 'm using node-sass, `/app/node_modules` works prpperly, but `./frontend/node_modules:/app/node_module` occurs such this error even though I'm using the same node version on local.

"Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux/musl 64-bit with Node.js 12.x"

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Your `yarn install` command creates a `node_modules` folder inside the Docker image. This created folder conflicts with the existing `frontend/node_modules` folder you have locally when trying to run with `./frontend/node_modules:/app/node_modules`. When you specify `/app/node_modules`, the container uses the directory created during the build step.

Comment: i tried `yarn install` in both local and also the docker container with the same node version, but still same.

Comment: @WilliamWang What is your host OS (Windows/macOS/Linux)? It's possible that a non-Linux host OS conflicts with the `node_modules` required in the container.

Comment: I'm using MacOS

Comment: so, what is the preferrable way between two?

Comment: If you're referring to how to mount volumes, the preferable way would be what currently works for you, using `/app/node_modules`. This installs the Node dependencies for Node version running in the container and not the Node version on macOS. Your error suggests the issue is the conflicting container vs. host Node versions.